# Fix broken display of SVG using ipywidgets DOMWidget in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: javascript, python, svg, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

### Summary

Please see [this example notebook](https://notebooks.azure.com/rickteachey/projects/geoselector/html/broken_example_svg_child.ipynb), which isn't working as expected. The third cell in the notebook *should* show an SVG window containing a simple green box. Example output is shown in cell 4*.

### Details

After running the notebook, a tooltip popup is displayed when I hover over the element in the console. Because of this popup I believe the SVG container and box (which is a PATH element) are definitely being created, they just aren't being displayed. The popup says they are being rendered at size 0x0.

How can I get this to work as expected, so that the contents of the SVG window show up in the output cell (cell #3)?

### Code

Here is the cell by cell code for convenience.

Cell #1

```py
import ipywidgets.widgets as widgets
from traitlets import Unicode


class Test(widgets.DOMWidget):
    _view_name = Unicode('TestView').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module = Unicode('test').tag(sync=True)
    _view_module_version = Unicode('0.1.0').tag(sync=True)
```

Cell #2

```
%%javascript

require.undef('test');

define('test', ["@jupyter-widgets/base"], function(widgets) {
    var TestView = widgets.DOMWidgetView.extend({

        render: function() {
            TestView.__super__.render.apply(this, arguments);
            var svg = document.createElement('svg');
            svg.innerHTML = '<path fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#66cc99" stroke="#555555" stroke-width="2.0" opacity="0.6" d="M 0.0,0.0 L 50.0,0.0 L 50.0,50.0 L 0.0,50.0 L 0.0,0.0 z" />';
            this.el.appendChild(svg);
            console.log(svg);  // when you hover over this line in the console, you can see the SVG has been created...
        },
    });

    return {
        TestView : TestView,
    };

});
```

Cell #3

```py
Test()  # this cell should output a green box
```

Cell #4: Example Output

```html
%%html
<svg>
<path fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#66cc99" stroke="#555555" stroke-width="2.0" opacity="0.6" d="M 0.0,0.0 L 50.0,0.0 L 50.0,50.0 L 0.0,50.0 L 0.0,0.0 z" />
</svg>
```

---

* NOTE: clone and run notebook to show the expected output at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out: for reasons I don't understand, you have to utilize `document.createElementNS()` function to add SVG, not `document.createElement()`. You also have to use `svg.setAttributeNS()` rather than `svg.setAttribute()`.

[Here's a fixed version](https://notebooks.azure.com/rickteachey/projects/geoselector/html/working_example_svg_child.ipynb) of the notebook. Code:

```
%%javascript

require.undef('test');

define('test', ["@jupyter-widgets/base"], function(widgets) {
    var TestView = widgets.DOMWidgetView.extend({

        render: function() {
            TestView.__super__.render.apply(this, arguments);
            var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
            var svg = document.createElementNS(xmlns, "svg");
            svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", "0 0 100 100");
            svg.innerHTML = '<path fill-rule="evenodd" fill="#66cc99" stroke="#555555" stroke-width="2.0" opacity="0.6" d="M 0.0,0.0 L 50.0,0.0 L 50.0,50.0 L 0.0,50.0 L 0.0,0.0 z" />';
            this.el.appendChild(svg);
            console.log(svg);  // when you hover over this line in the console, you can see the SVG has been created...
        },
    });

    return {
        TestView : TestView,
    };

});
```

Comment: Ah that's a really good find. I played with your code a bit when you posted the issue on the jupyter-widgets repo, but I couldn't figure out what was going wrong (mostly because I don't know anything about SVGs).

Comment: @PascalBugnion Yeah I don't know jack about javascript OR SVG, this is suuuuuuch a dumb gotcha. OMG.

Comment: @PascalBugnion and [now I'm trying to figure out](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/pull/3600#issuecomment-503823056) how to attach an SVG to the backbone view. Every discussion of how to do this I've found appears to be years old.